# How To Put Non Removable Credit Links

Tags: hyperlink, blogger

I am with blogger platform, and I want to know the code when template developers use if their credits are removed so the template redirects to their own website. I want to know what is that code and how it is implemented because I am developing some blogger templates so I want to place my credits not to be removed.

Comment: can show some template having this functionality ?

Comment: Those are `Obfuscated Javascripts` that resides within the basic Javascripts like Sliders, Featured Posts and other `JS` parts.

Comment: yes, just go to [link](http://www.templateism.com/)] and download any template. then change the footer credit then refresh your blog. then see what happens